# Class 'Mage_Connect_Rest_Builder' not found in /home/pacificpheromone/public_html/downloader/lib/Mage/Connect/Command/Package.php on line 114

Tags: php, magento

Okay so I'm trying to install a Magento module, M2ePro. But whenever I enter the installation key it gives me this error:

```
Class 'Mage_Connect_Rest_Builder' not found in /home/pacificpheromone/public_html/downloader/lib/Mage/Connect/Command/Package.php on line 114
```

However, when I check line 114 of Package.php it does in fact show that class...

```
$rest = Mage_Connect_Rest_Builder::getAdapter($config->protocol);
```

So what could be the problem? Appreciate any help.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

it can be problem of magento version not having the Mage_Connect_Rest_Builder class or file.
my problem was solved by changing the downloader folder from root to this git hub source.
https://github.com/sohagan/magento-1.9.2.0/tree/master/downloader/